# What is the advantage of having a client-side MTA in the SMTP network?

Tags: email, smtp

A standard email delivery uses at least 2 SMTP connections:

- From the sender to the sender's MTA
- From the sender's MTA to the receiver's MTA

and requires at least two SMTP servers, the first one being a **relay**.

Instead of this routing / relay infrastructure, the client **could directly send its messages to the receiver's MTA**, e.g. bypassing the relay step.

I get that there are some advantages, such as :

- **authentication delegation and greylisting**: The receiver can trust the sender's MTA to authenticate the sender, so it is not necessary to be able to authenticate the sender.
- **advantages of the client-server architecture**: the client's MTA being a server, it can provide easily more functions (be more easily secured etc...) than a client application. For example, back when being connected to the Internet was costly, the MTA server could mutualise the Internet connection.

But it seems these are only advantages, and not a design constraint today (embedding a library on the client is not a problem anymore).
Are there some  reasons that require using a client MTA today, or is it because of the technological inertia of these protocols (e.g. the difficulty to change a standard that is well established and implemented)?

Comment: Most email with a single relay is either internal mail (e.g. you sent mail to your coworker) or else spam.  Noting the single external relay is a pretty good indicator of spam. See also [this post describing SMTP relay hops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50475710/519360).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several compelling reasons to use a client-side MTA.  Here are two:

1) The sending MTA does the DNS queries to figure out which mail server it needs to contact to reach the receiver's MTA.

2) If the sending MTA can't reach the receiver's mail server, it can retry delivery later on.  Or, it could fall back to using one of the receiving domain's higher-distance MX records (if any exist).

You could always write this functionality in your mail client, but if you do that, you are well on your way to making your mail client an MTA.

There are other reasons.  For example, if the sending MTA handles mail for multiple senders, it can batch emails: if it has multiple emails destined for gmail addresses, for example, it can send them all over the same connection.  That way it doesn't have to open and shut down a connection for every single email.  This becomes even more advantageous if it needs to negotiate TLS and/or AUTH.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion is far too complicated for most users in "spam era".
It may be worth the effort required for some but sadly mostly for spammers.

Sending via "sender MTA/SMTP server" grossly simplifies email sending, both troubleshooting *by sender* and email client implementation.